# Selecting the next radio button in a group

Tags: c#, radio-button

Is there a standard way to programmatically select/check the next radio button in a group of radio buttons? The behaviour I'm looking for is similar to the default arrow key press event for radio buttons that are grouped in a container: When I press the arrow keys, the next (or previous) radio button is automatically selected and checked.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I made this in such way:

```
    var rads = panel1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>(); // Get all radioButtons of desired panel

    rads.OrderBy(r => r.Top); // sort them. Please specify what you mean "next" here. I assume that you need next one at the bottom

    // find first checked and set checked for next one
    for (int i = 0; i < rads.Count()-1; i++) 
    {
        if (rads.ElementAt(i).Checked)
        {
            rads.ElementAt(i + 1).Checked = true; 
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The sorting method that Windows seems to use when cycling through the radio buttons is ordered first by TabIndex and then by the z-order whenever multiple radio buttons have the same TabIndex. Also, the method proposed here does not allow the the selection to loop back to the first radio button. I did take inspiration from your answer, though. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only check one `RadioButton` per container. That's the point of a radio button. If you want to use a `CheckBox` instead you could use the following code:

```
foreach (CheckBox control in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    control.Checked = true;
}
```

If you want the controls checked sequentailly you can do

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    foreach (CheckBox control in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        control.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) (() => control.Checked = true));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}).Start();
```

Reading your original post another time, I'm struggling to understand exactly what you mean. Could you please elaborate so I can update my response?

Comment: Clarification: Say I have 5 radio buttons in a panel. Say that the third one is currently selected (checked). I want to programmatically select (check) the next radio button in the panel without using the mouse or keyboard to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution: (if your application has focus...)

```
//assuming you are at the first radio button
SendKeys({DOWN});
```

More Difficult Solution:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall.aspx

```
//Write method to get window element for the window you wish to manipulate
//Open an instance of notepad and the WindowTitle is: "Untitled - Notepad"
//you could use other means of getting to the Window element ...
AutomationElement windowElement = getWindowElement("Untitled - Notepad");

//Use System.Windows.Automation to find all radio buttons in the WindowElement
//pass the window element into this method
//This method will return all of the radio buttons in the element that is passed in
//however, if you have a Pane inside of the WIndow and then, the buttons are contained
//in the pane, you will have to get to the pane and then pass the pane into the findradiobuttons method
AutomationElementCollection radioButtons = FindRadioButtons(windowElement);

//could iterate through the radioButtons to determine which is selected...
//then select the next index etc.    

//then programmatically select the radio button
//pass the selected radioButton AutomationElement into a method that Invokes the Click etc.
clickButtonUsingUIAutomation(radioButtons[0]);

/// <summary> 
/// Finds all enabled buttons in the specified window element. 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="elementWindowElement">An application or dialog window.</param>
/// <returns>A collection of elements that meet the conditions.</returns>
AutomationElementCollection FindRadioButtons(AutomationElement elementWindowElement)
{
    if (elementWindowElement == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    Condition conditions = new AndCondition(
      new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true),
      new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, 
          ControlType.RadioButton)
      );

    // Find all children that match the specified conditions.
    AutomationElementCollection elementCollection = 
    elementWindowElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, conditions);
    return elementCollection;
}

    private AutomationElement getWindowElement(string windowTitle)
    {
        AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.RootElement;
        AutomationElement result = null;
        foreach (AutomationElement window in root.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window)))
        {
            try
            {
                if (window.Current.Name.Contains(windowTitle) && window.Current.IsKeyboardFocusable)
                {
                    result = window;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void ClickButtonUsingUIAutomation(AutomationElement control)
    {
        // Test for the control patterns of interest for this sample. 
        object objPattern;
        ExpandCollapsePattern expcolPattern;

        if (true == control.TryGetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern, out objPattern))
        {
            expcolPattern = objPattern as ExpandCollapsePattern;
            if (expcolPattern.Current.ExpandCollapseState != ExpandCollapseState.LeafNode)
            {
                Button expcolButton = new Button();
                //expcolButton.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 5);
                expcolButton.Height = 20;
                expcolButton.Width = 100;
                //expcolButton.Content = "ExpandCollapse";
                expcolButton.Tag = expcolPattern;
                expcolPattern.Expand();
                //SelectListItem(control, "ProcessMethods");
                //expcolButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(ExpandCollapse_Click);
                //clientTreeViews[treeviewIndex].Children.Add(expcolButton);
            }
        }
        TogglePattern togPattern;
        if (true == control.TryGetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern, out objPattern))
        {
            togPattern = objPattern as TogglePattern;
            Button togButton = new Button();
            //togButton.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 5);
            togButton.Height = 20;
            togButton.Width = 100;
            //togButton.Content = "Toggle";
            togButton.Tag = togPattern;
            togPattern.Toggle();
            //togButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Toggle_Click);
            //clientTreeViews[treeviewIndex].Children.Add(togButton);
        }
        InvokePattern invPattern;
        if (true == control.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out objPattern))
        {
            invPattern = objPattern as InvokePattern;
            Button invButton = new Button();
            //invButton.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            invButton.Height = 20;
            invButton.Width = 100;
            //invButton.Content = "Invoke";
            invButton.Tag = invPattern;
            //invButton.Click += new EventHandler(Invoke_Click);
            invPattern.Invoke();

            //clientTreeViews[treeviewIndex].Children.Add(invButton);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems as if there is no standard way to handle this. I ended up taking inspiration from Andrey's solution and writing an extension method that can be called from any particular RadioButton within a group of RadioButtons.

```
public static void CheckNextInGroup(this RadioButton radioButton, bool forward) {
    var parent = radioButton.Parent;
    var radioButtons = parent.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>();  //get all RadioButtons in the relevant container
    var ordered = radioButtons.OrderBy(i => i.TabIndex).ThenBy(i => parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(i)).ToList();  //Sort them like Windows does
    var indexChecked = ordered.IndexOf(radioButtons.Single(i => i.Checked)); //Find the index of the one currently checked
    var indexDesired = (indexChecked + (forward ? 1 : -1)) % ordered.Count;  //This allows you to step forward and loop back to the first RadioButton
    if (indexDesired < 0) indexDesired += ordered.Count;  //Allows you to step backwards to loop to the last RadioButton
    ordered[indexDesired].Checked = true;
}
```

Then, from anywhere that has access to your particular RadioButton, you can cause the next or previous RadioButton in its collection to get checked. Like this:

```
radioButton1.CheckNextInGroup(true); //Checks the next one in the collection
radioButton1.CheckNextInGroup(false); //Checks the previous one in the collection
```