# How to start WinForms application and check if a button exist in it using C# code?

Tags: c#, winforms, process.start

I have to make a simple tool that does the following:

- starts a WinForms application from a file on the local disk
- checks if the window title matches a predefined string
- checks if a button exists in the application window

I use this code to start the application:

```
Process myApp = new Process();
myApp.StartInfo.FileName = "somePath";
app.Start(somePath);
```

I use the `myApp.MainWindowTitle` property to check the window name.

I wonder how to check that something exists in the application window, for example to ensure a button is present.

The purpose of this tool is to check only if the application starts correctly. I am now tring to find out what exactly is the Visual Studio CodedUI feature and how it can help, but do not have any results so far.

I would be very grateful if someone can give me some information and\or ideas.

Comment: if app doesn't start properly does it trows some exceptions ? If so maybe is better idea to log exceptions and then simply examine log

Comment: Its unlikely you will be able to detect if a Button exists within the process window.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although this was an answer to a different question, you may find [John Bartel's post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14350968/239791) helpful. Look at the second section of his solution that he labeled "More Difficult Solution". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have dig up old dusty Delphi code from long ago, and translated to c# :

Class that will enumerate all child windows :

```
  public static class WindowsEnumerator
  {
    private static List<IntPtr> childs = new List<IntPtr>();

    public static List<WindowInfo> EnumerateChildWindows(IntPtr parentHandle)
    {
      var result = new List<WindowInfo>();
      childs.Clear();
      EnumChildWindows(parentHandle, Enumerator, IntPtr.Zero);

      foreach (IntPtr handle in childs)
      {
        result.Add(new WindowInfo(handle));  
      }

      return result;
    }

    private static bool Enumerator(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam)
    {
      childs.Add(hwnd);
      return true;
    }

    internal delegate bool WindowEnumProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, WindowEnumProc func, IntPtr lParam);
  }

  public class WindowInfo
  {
    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public string ClassName { get; private set; }

    public WindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
      this.Handle = hwnd;

      var sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
      var txtLen = GetWindowText(this.Handle, sb, sb.Capacity);
      if (txtLen > 0)
        this.Text = sb.ToString();
      else
        this.Text = "";


      var sbc = new StringBuilder(256);
      var clsLen = GetClassName(this.Handle, sbc, sbc.Capacity);
      if (clsLen > 0)
        this.ClassName = sbc.ToString();
      else
        this.ClassName = "";
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);
  }
```

And then you just have to find a button with static method WindowsEnumerator.EnumerateChildWindows, WinForms button has a "BUTTON" string in a ClassName, and let's presume that your button is named button1 (and hope that you are not using such names) :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var exeProcess = Process.Start(@"w:\kanta\temp\ExeWithButtonInsideGroupBox.exe");
  while (exeProcess.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() == 0)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(10);
  };     

  var windows = WindowsEnumerator.EnumerateChildWindows(exeProcess.MainWindowHandle);
  exeProcess.Kill();

  bool myButtonExists = windows.FirstOrDefault(wnd => wnd.ClassName.Contains("BUTTON") && wnd.Text == "button1") != null;

  MessageBox.Show(myButtonExists.ToString());
}
```